# OpenShift/OKD cluster - Use with external/outside domain

Tags: openshift-online-2, openshift-origin, openshift, openshift-online-3, openshift-4

I have an OpenShift/OKD cluster already up and running and using the following domain...

```
certain.domain
```

Within this domain I have these (among others) features working...

```
console-openshift-console.apps.okdsubdom.certain.domain
oauth-openshift.apps.okdsubdom.certain.domain
prometheus-k8s-openshift-monitoring.apps.okdsubdom.certain.domain
grafana-openshift-monitoring.apps.okdsubdom.certain.domain
alertmanager-main-openshift-monitoring.apps.okdsubdom.certain.domain
```

---

**QUESTION:** I own this other (external/outside) domain...

```
another.domain
```

.... and I need the resources mentioned above to respond to it as below...

```
console-openshift-console.apps.okdsubdom.another.domain
oauth-openshift.apps.okdsubdom.another.domain
prometheus-k8s-openshift-monitoring.apps.okdsubdom.another.domain
grafana-openshift-monitoring.apps.okdsubdom.another.domain
alertmanager-main-openshift-monitoring.apps.okdsubdom.another.domain
```

.

---

**IMPORTANT:** Our main difficulty these days is the Web Console because it doesn't use relative paths for its URLs. That is, its (absolute path) URLs are in the domain `certain.domain` and we **can't find a simple way** to make it use and consume the URL `another.domain`.

Thanks! =D

Comment: what about creating a CNAME DNS record from the first domain to the second one?

Comment: Hmmm... How would that be? =D

Comment: are `certain.domain` and `another.domain` publicly accessed? configured through some DNS provider or your private DNS server (and are you able to change them)? is `certain.domain` a private one or just a defferent one? all those questions are for answering better but in general, a CNAME record points to another DNS record unlike a regular dns record which points to an IP address (very generally speaking). In your case you might benefit from pointing `another.domain` to `certain.domain` using a CNAME record or alike.